# Calculation of step-up / step-down output voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, step-down, step-up

I am trying to build a step-up and step-down circuit from a DC-DC converter IC.

This is from the datasheet:

[image]

I have two questions in relation to this:

1. The value of the resistor in the red box. It says 0.22. Is this in ohms? 0.22 ohms seems quite peculiar to me.
2. Regarding the `Vout` calculation. You can look at the red line in the bottom of the screenshot. It looks like `Vout` is calculated by selecting values only for the `R1` and `R2` resistors. Is this correct? Shouldn't `Vin` be taken into consideration as well?

Comment: Please add the datasheet link

Comment: What is peculiar about 0.22 ohm? It is a current sensing resistor and has to be a small value.

Comment: 1. Lazy of them to leave out the unit when they have it elsewhere. Could theoretically also be that the Omega-sign was not interpreted correctly and the PDF ended up with a blank character instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\$R_{SC}=0.22\Omega\$. It has to be small, to stay cool, and to avoid becoming a bottleneck for significant inductor current. Such small values are very common in current sensing applications.

The regulator does not need to know what the input voltage is, in order to know if its own *output* is at the correct potential. To determine if the output is too high or too low, some fraction of it, a fraction defined by R1 and R2, is compared against a fixed internal 1.25V reference. No other information is needed, the formula is correct.